# How to dynamically add and remove text input fields in Svelte correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, input, textfield, svelte

I am new to Svelte and web development and I hope you could point me in the right direction.

The current code belongs in a svelte component.
As shown here: https://svelte.dev/repl/f0e5c30117724ec38b7d19781d2c4de6?version=3.48.0

It is supposed to show one text field by default, while allowing for an additional text field to be added and removed on dynamically added buttons.
Currently, this code can dynamically add the text field, however, it cannot dynamically remove the text field on button click.

I believe there might be an error in the GetDynamicElement function. However, I am not sure where exactly. Any suggestions?

p.s. I know there are answers here that are close, but I don't think they are applicable in this situation, especially on Svelte.

```
<script>
  var num_links = 1;
  let container;

  const GetDynamicElement = (value) => {
    return (
      '<input name = "DynamicField" type="text" size =111  id =link  placeholder="Enter Next link! " value =  "' +
      value +
      '" />' +
      '<input type="button" value="Remove" on:click = {RemoveField(this)}>'
      // "RemoveSuggestionCart(this)" />'
    );
  };

  const addField = () => {
    if (num_links < 2) {
      console.log("addField");
      const div = document.createElement("DIV");
      div.innerHTML = GetDynamicElement("");
      container.appendChild(div); // Append timetable space
      num_links += 1;
    }
  };

  //Removes the entire division inclusive of it's text field.
  const RemoveField = (div) => {
    console.log("RemoveField");
    div.removeChild(div.parentNode);
    num_links -= 1;
  };
</script>



<div>
  <input
    name="DynamicField"
    type="text"
    size="121"
    id="link"
    placeholder="Enter First Link!"
  />
  <div bind:this={container} />
</div>

<button on:click|preventDefault={addField}>[+ add timetable link]</button>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: Could you provide a playground link?

Comment: https://svelte.dev/repl/f0e5c30117724ec38b7d19781d2c4de6?version=3.48.0

Heres the link ! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should absolutely not build HTML from strings in JS. Svelte exists to prevent exactly that and the security issues that come with it.

Answer (score 2):

Add/ remove fields and have a button to log or send to endpoint or whatever with "Log" button.

```
    <script>
    // to display one empty inputs before clicking add needed
    let values=[{
       "url": "",
       "name": "",
    }]; 
        
    const addField = () => {
       values = [...values, {url: '', name: ''}]
    };
        
    const removeField = () => {
       values = values.slice(0, values.length-1)
    };
    </script>
        
    {#each values as v, i}
       <div>
          <input id={i} type="text" bind:value={values[i].url} placeholder="url"/>
          <input id={i} type="text" bind:value={values[i].name} placeholder="name"/>
       </div>
    {/each}
{#if values.length >= 2}
   <input type="button" value="Remove" on:click={removeField}>
{/if]
<button on:click|preventDefault={addField}>Add</button>
<button on:click={() => console.log(values)}>Log Me</button>
```

Try: https://svelte.dev/repl/2441993f8d9946aa894bf07a8a8f9b4f

Edited: thanks @Corrl - edited nicer.

Comment: Better include a simple version of the code in your answer and not just the link to the Repl

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will change when on PC again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `num_link` and svelte's [`#each`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-each) to create to inputs using svelte:

```
{#each Array(num_links) as _, i}
<div>
  <input
    name="DynamicField"
    type="text"
    size="121"
    id={`link_${i}`}
    placeholder="Enter First Link!"
  />
</div>
{/each}
```

Working example: https://svelte.dev/repl/04169e030b6944258cfd07af15873b48?version=3.48.0

Comment: (If the data is not directly sent as part of a form, the `num_links` should be replaced by a proper array that also holds the data that was entered into the fields. The fields can be synchronized by using [`bind:value`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-bind-property). Otherwise you again end up with unnecessary DOM access in JS.)

Comment: @H.B. do you mind to show the working solution?

Comment: @KasparL.Palgi Check out [this official example](https://svelte.dev/examples/each-block-bindings).